# How do I disable or change keyboard shortcut that starts Firefox Devtools?

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I often copy paste from a terminal where I need use `<C-C>` instead of `<C-c>`. So when I'm copying and pasting between terminal and Firefox, I often end up using `<C-C>` in Firefox, which annoyingly opens the devtools, stealing focus.

I'm looking for a way to either (in order of preference):

1. Remap `<C-C>` to literally anything else, preferably `<C-c>`
2. Completely disable the `<C-C>` binding, as I don't do any web development
3. Disable devtools (toggling `devtools.enabled` opens up a new tab when I press the shortcut)
4. If focus is on a Firefox window, prevent X from sending that shortcut to the application
5. Add a new shortcut to close devtools when it's opened (this may already exist, but I couldn't find any mention of it)

Comment: #5 Try to press `F12`

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that in the docs :|

I'm still hoping someone will be able to solve #1 or #2, but now I don't have to fumble around with my mouse now. 

Thank you.